# How to compare two string lists and return matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-comparison

I want to take two lists and find the values that appear in both.

```
A = ['A7', 'B4', 'B7']
B = ['A7', 'B7', 'C7', 'D7', 'E7', 'F7', 'G7', 'H7', 'I7']
returnMatches()
```

would return `['A7', 'B7']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
set(A) & set(B)
```

You can even construct them as sets from the beginning:

```
A = {'A7', 'B4', 'B7'}
```

Comment: None of those suggestions results in a `list`.